# htmlunit and htmlunit-driver differences

Tags: htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

What is the difference between original http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net and Seleium implementation known as htmlunit-driver?

Answer (score 2):

There is no real difference, htmlunt-driver is only a small wrapper to make HtmlUnit available as selenium driver.